# Pass in Array to Select Case

Tags: vb.net, linq, select-case

this may be a dense question and I'm not finding it to be a dup of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555197/what-is-the-vb-net-select-case-statement-logic-with-case-or-ing), but I need some help with understanding if an array can be used in a Select Case statement.

I have a sub routine that I will create a string array dynamically. The XML is also listed, but it could be any of the values listed below. It will be something like this:

```
Dim offensiveLine() As String = New String() {"center", "right wing", "left wing"}
Dim defensiveLine As String = "defense"
Dim playerInfo = <Player><Name>John</Name><Position val="right wing"/></Player>
```

What I want to do is see if this player is in one of the offensiveLine. So I say:

```
Dim playerPosition = playerInfo.Position.@val
Select Case playerPosition
Case offensiveLine
'do something
Case defensiveLine
'do something
Case Else 
'do nothing
End Select
```

Here is lies the issue: `Case offensiveLine` is invalid. I know I could write out `Case "center", "right wing", "left wing"`, but that would defeat the purpose of what I'm trying to do, which is to make a generalized variable that is an array that can be read from in a Case statement. Secondly, I know I can't create a variable like `Dim offensiveLine = ""center", "right wing", "left wing""` and pass that in.

Any insight on how I may be able to pass in an array to a Case statement and have each one evaluated?

Comment: Why an array and not an Enum?

Comment: Good question, I hadn't thought of that. Do you think an Enum would do the same thing here, i.e. I could have an enum that would have 3 string values and I just pass in the Enum name for all three values to be evaluated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Select..Case` construct does not work like that.  However, it is easy to test if an element exists in an array:

```
If offensiveLine.Contains(playerPosition) Then
    'Do something
ElseIf defensiveLine.Contains(playerPosition) Then
    'Do something else
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider using an if clause here rather than a switch.  Try this logic: if offensiveLine contains playerPosition, then offensive line, etc.

Comment: thanks Norla. i can probably do that, but looking specifically if an array can be passed into a switch. An strongly typed array of choices can be part of a Case expressionlist (like: Case "one", "two", "three"). I have the same need, I just need to pass it in dynamically instead of strongly type it.

Answer (score 3):

You actually *can* use a `Select` statement:

```
Dim playerPosition = playerInfo.Position.@val
Select Case True
    Case offensiveLine.Contains(playerPosition)
        'do something
    Case defensiveLine.Contains(playerPosition)
        'do something
    Case Else 
        'do something - otherwise you don't need the 'Case Else'
End Select
```

The trick is the *True* in the first line of the `Select`.